reCAPTCHA for a web-to-lead Salesforce
I wanted to create a reCAPTCHA for a web-to-lead form. When I attempt to create it through Google, I input erjcchouston.org for the domain. However, every time I run my code, I receive an error that says 'Invalid domain for site key.' Could you please help me understand which part I should change so that my reCAPTCHA works correctly? Screenshot attached
I'm looking to implement a reCAPTCHA for my Salesforce Web-to-Lead page. I've already created a case with Salesforce, but unfortunately, they weren't able to assist me.

If you're doing testing locally, you may need to add localhost to the list of allowed domains. If it's already live, check that you are using a public key and not the private key. It is also possible for your key to be expired and regenerating a new one could solve this problem.
